# How to separate user's input with two separators? And controlling the users input

Tags: python

I want to separate the users input using two different separators which are `":"` and `";"`

Like the user should input 4 subject and it's amounts.  The format should be:

```
(Subject:amount;Subject:amount;Subject:amount;Subject:amount)
```

If the input is wrong it should print "Invalid Input "

Here's my code but I can only used one separator and how can I control the users input?

```
B = input("Enter 4 subjects and amount separated by (;) like Math:90;Science:80:").split(";")
```

Please help. I can't figure it out.

Comment: First split by `;`, then split each part by `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with using regular expressions in python you could use the following code:

```
import re
output_list = re.split("[;:]", input_string)
```

Where inside the square brackets you include all the characters (also known as delimiters) that you want to split by, just make sure to keep the quotes around the square brackets as that makes a regex string (what we are using to tell the computer what to split)

Further reading on regex can be found here if you feel like it: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

However, if you want to do it without importing anything you could do this, which is another possible solution (and I would recommend against, but it gets the job done well):

```
input_string = input_string.replace(";", ":")
output_list = input_string.split(":")
```

Which works by first replacing all of the semicolons in the input string with colons (it could also work the other way around) and then splitting by the remaining character (in this case the colons)

Hope this helped, as it is my first answer on Stack overflow.